# Sentiment analysis histogram of a movie's human faces

Tags: video, sentiment-analysis

I want to generate a happy/sad/angry/bored/normal histogram of a faces of a movie.

The program would

1. Detect human faces
2. Evaluate the sentiment(s) of each face
3. Draw an histogram showing how many happy/sad/angry/bored/normal people are on screen at every point of the movie

The result could look like this:

```
Happy faces
 ^
3|        ■■                ■
2|     ■■■■■■              ■■
1|  ■■■■■■■■■■■ ■■■      ■■■■
 +---------------------------> Time

Sad faces
 ^
3|            ■
2|■           ■  ■■■■      ■
1|■■■         ■■ ■■■■■■■■  ■■
 +---------------------------> Time
```

- No need to recognize an actor throughout the movie: just count faces without keeping track of each individual character is OK.
- Free, or at least free trial.